# How do I represent and work with n-bit vectors in Python?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitarray, bitvector

In an assignment I am currently working on we need to work with bit vectors, but I am very unsure of how to do this in Python. They should be able to be from 4 bits to 20 bits. I have never worked with bit vector before, but I guess that one would one create arrays of unsigned bytes that you manipulated using the usual AND/OR/XOR operations.

The **important restriction** here is: I cannot rely on *any* libraries other than those supplied with standard Python.

I think I know how I would do this in C using arrays of 8 bit unsigned bytes: 
e.g. to turn the 18th bit of a zeroed array into a one, I would do something like 
my_bit_array[3] &= 1<<2

But since Python is dynamically typed and does not have a built-in array type, how would I go about doing this in a pythonic way?

And is it possible (how?) to express a bit vector of size 20? I am thinking of perhaps making a 24 bit / 3 byte vector and ignoring the 4 bits.

Comment: What is the issue with relying on external libraries?

Comment: @ezod: Probably because this is homework.

Comment: @S.Lott: yes, this is in relation to that, but this part has very little to do with that. as you see, I could have done this in C, but I would like to know how to do it in Python, using the built-ins of the language. That is a general question of relevance to others.

Comment: @oligofren: In that case, suggestions of external libraries would seem to be just as useful to you, assuming they are free -- you can look at the source and see how they've done it (using the built-ins of the language) for your academic interest.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The library [BitVector](https://pypi.org/project/BitVector/) is a pure-Python library for this purpose, and should suit the needs you specified.

Comment: Good library. Didn't use it, but learned a lot from reading the code. Turns out that in the nitty-gritty details the author of BitVector is using an array of (8 bit) bytes, just like I was pondering.

Answer (score 45):

I'm surprised that no one has mentioned `int`s (or I guess `long` in Python 2).  `int`s can be arbitrarily large, you can use bitwise operators on them, they're fast, and the code looks like bit twiddling code in C (I consider that to be an advantage).

```
x = 0 # empty
x |= 1<<19 # set bit 19
x &= ~(1<<19) # clear bit 19
x ^= 1<<19 # toggle bit 19
x = ~x # invert *all* bits, all the way to infinity
mask = ((1<<20)-1) # define a 20 bit wide mask
x &= mask # ensure bits 20 and higher are 0
x ^= mask # invert only bits 0 through 19

(x >> 19) & 1 # test bit 19
(x >> 16) & 0xf # get bits 16 through 20.
```

I've used this for bitvectors hundreds of bits long.

Comment: Takes seconds per operation on an i7 when you have tens of billions of bits.

Comment: This works great for smallish vectors, like 128 bit. Very simple and built-in.

Comment: I have a bitvector with two million bits and it seems very slow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52440611/is-python-bitwise-shift-really-slow

Answer (score 9):

It has lists, which you can populate with bools:

```
[False] * 20
```

Comment: Would this occupy 20 bytes or 20 bits of memory? I need to use *lots* of these

Comment: It would occupy 20+1 pointers. True and False are singletons.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I guess I will have to go with the structs module in that case.

Answer (score 9):

The [bitarray](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray) module does this efficiently with booleans.

Answer (score 3):

Use [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module.

Comment: Could you give me an example of creating a 3 byte array and setting a bit? I do not know the basic binary operators in Python.

Comment: I used it only once, when I needed to write some low level stuff. The docs are very fine, though.

Comment: @oligofren see http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/struct/index.html for a walkthrough. btw the site makes a very fine alternative for getting used to the stdlib.

Answer (score 3):

A bit dated but I'm going to leave another stdlib option here just for comparison sake. It is also easy to do this using the [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ctypes.html#bit-fields-in-structures-and-unions) module.

For example:

> And is it possible (how?) to express a bit vector of size 20 ?
>   I am thinking of perhaps making a 24 bit / 3 byte vector and ignoring the 4
>   bits.

```
class Simple(ctypes.LittleEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
                 ('one', ctypes.c_ubyte, 8),
                 ('two', ctypes.c_ubyte, 8),
                 ('three', ctypes.c_ubyte, 8)
               ]

s = Simple(0, 2, 256)
bytearray(s)        # bytearray(b'\x00\x02\x00')
s = Simple(0, 2, 255)
bytearray(s)        # bytearray(b'\x00\x02\xff')

class Simple(ctypes.BigEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
                 ('one', ctypes.c_ubyte, 8),
                 ('two', ctypes.c_ubyte, 8),
                 ('three', ctypes.c_ubyte, 8)
               ]

s = Simple(0, 2, 256)
bytearray(s)        # bytearray(b'\x00\x02\x00')
s = Simple(0, 2, 255)
bytearray(s)        # bytearray(b'\x00\x02\xff')

s.two |= 3
bytearray(s)        # bytearray(b'\x00\x03\xff')
```

or something more straight forward like this:

```
class bit_vector(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('bits', c_uint32, 24),
                ('unused', c_uint32, 8),
                ]

bv = bit_vector()
# turn on the 18th bit -- being explicit just to demo it
bv.bits |= int('000000000000000001000000', 2)
bin(bv.bits)   # 0b1000000
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also the pure-Python **[python-bitstring](http://code.google.com/p/python-bitstring/)** (with Python 3 support).