# Replacing one character of a string in python

Tags: python

In python, are strings mutable?  The line `someString[3] = "a"` throws the error

> TypeError: 'str' object does not
>   support item assignment

I can see why (as I could have written someString[3] = "test" and that would obviously be illegal) but is there a method to do this in python?

Comment: I have a binary string and on certain conditions, I want to flip a specific 0 to 1.

Comment: But generally, I'd want to flip a specific letter x to y.  Right now I'm dealing with binary strings but it's a general inquiry

Comment: Another tip: If you're doing "binary strings", i.e. strings consisting of only 1s and 0s, check out a library like BitVector, which is faster and more convenient for bit vector manipulation.

Also, see a question on bit vectors in Python at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147848/how-do-i-represent-and-work-with-n-bit-vectors-in-python/2147873#2147873

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Python strings are immutable, which means that they do not support item or slice assignment. You'll have to build a new string using i.e. `someString[:3] + 'a' + someString[4:]` or some other suitable approach.

Answer (score 20):

Instead of storing your value as a string, you could use a list of characters:

```
>>> l = list('foobar')
>>> l[3] = 'f'
>>> l[5] = 'n'
```

Then if you want to convert it back to a string to display it, use this:

```
>>> ''.join(l)
'foofan'
```

If you are changing a lot of characters one at a time, this method will be considerably faster than building a new string each time you change a character.

Answer (score 4):

In new enough pythons you can also use the builtin `bytearray` type, which is mutable. See the stdlib documentation. But "new enough" here means 2.6 or up, so that's not necessarily an option.

In older pythons you have to create a fresh `str` as mentioned above, since those are immutable. That's usually the most readable approach, but sometimes using a different kind of mutable sequence (like a list of characters, or possibly an `array.array`) makes sense. `array.array` is a bit clunky though, and usually avoided.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> s = "1234567890"
>>> mutable = ctypes.create_string_buffer(s)
>>> mutable[3] = "a"
>>> print mutable.value
123a567890
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
someString.replace(str(list(someString)[3]),"a")
```

Comment: when `someString = '0001'`  and you want to replace 2nd 0 you get `'aaa1'` which is not desired

Answer (score -3):

Just define a new string equaling to what you want to do with your current string.

```
a = str.replace(str[n],"")
 return a
```

Comment: This will remove all instances of whichever character is the `n`th character in the string. Also, you shouldn't name your variables after Python builtins (`str` in this case)