# how can I add mark every two index in String

Tags: python

```
def Change(_text):
    L = len(_text)
    _i = 2
    _text[_i] = "*"
    _i += 2
    print(_text)
```

How can I add a mark e.g:* every two Index In String

Comment: duplicate maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most "pythonic" way to iterate over a list in chunks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `_` in your variables? If it is for any of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5893946/4041795) reasons then you are OK, if it is a made up syntax, try not to use it as it might cause unnecessary confusion.

As for your code, try:

```
def change_text(text): 
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if i % 2 == 0: # check if i = even (not odd)
            print(text[:i] + "*" + text[i+1:])
```

When you run `change_text("tryout string")` the output will look like:

```
*ryout string
tr*out string
tryo*t string
tryout*string
tryout s*ring
tryout str*ng
tryout strin*
```

If you meant something else, name a example input and wished for output.

See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

**PS**: Please realize that strings are immutable in Python, so you cannot actually change a string, only create new ones from it.. if you want to actually change it you might be better of saving it as a list for example. Like they have done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2165236/4041795).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to separate every two letters with an asterix?

```
testtesttest
te*st*te*st*te*st
```

You could do this using `itertools.zip_longest` to split the string up, and `'*'.join` to rebuild it with the markers inserted

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def add_marker(s):
    return '*'.join([''.join(x) for x in zip_longest(*[iter(s)]*2, fillvalue='')])
```