# How to create an array of bits in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, bit

How can I declare a bit array of a very large size, say 6 million bits?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This could be used for something like a bitmap.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147848/how-do-i-represent-and-work-with-n-bit-vectors-in-python -- hesitant to mark as duplicate.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
from bitarray import bitarray

a = bitarray(2**20)
```

You can check out more info about this module at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/

Comment: _bitarray_ does not seem to be in the standard python, but is instead a feature offered by _pypy_.

Comment: I think you mean *pip*

Comment: I think you mean “included in *PyPI*”, the Python Package Index. :p

Answer (score 28):

The [bitstring](https://github.com/scott-griffiths/bitstring) module may help:

```
from bitstring import BitArray
a = BitArray(6000000)
```

This will take less than a megabyte of memory, and it's easy to set, read, slice and interpret bits. Unlike the bitarray module it's pure Python, plus it works for Python 3.

See [the documentation](https://bitstring.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for more details.

Answer (score 11):

This one-liner converts bytes to a list of True/False bit values. Might be not performant for 6M bits but for small flags it should be fine and does not need additional dependencies.

```
>>> flags = bytes.fromhex(b"beef")
>>> bits =  [flags[i//8] & 1 << i%8 != 0 for i in range(len(flags) * 8)]
>>> print(bits)
[False, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True]
```

Answer (score 11):

Quite easily

```
bitarray60000 = 1<<60000
```

With that, you can use bitshift operator to your heart content.
For instance, position 2 set True would be:

```
bitarray60000 | 1<<2
```

Getting bit from position 2

```
bitarray60000 & 1<<2
```

I guess the idea is quite simple. Though some operations might be tricky.

Comment: This is not quite the same when it comes to the length of the array. For example, bitarrays '000' and '0' should be distinct.

Comment: First, one can encapsulate the logic inside the class. 

Second, I thought of "1000" where the leading 1 determines the array's length. Thus, 1000 is an array with three slots, not four as one might think. With this little twist, it is fine.

As I said the implementation may be tricky but it should work.

Comment: Yes, the leading 1 is a little hacky for finding the array length and getting the raw bits out. But it's an interesting memory optimization.

Comment: You can actually use a different base, say three, for three options. It takes some math to store them but it is doable.

Answer (score 10):

Get the bitarray module using

```
pip install bitarray
```

Then, this code will create a bit array of size 6 million,

```
from bitarray import bitarray
bit_array = bitarray(6000000)
```

You can initialize all the bits to zero using

```
bit_array.setall(0)
```

To set a particular bit, say bit number 25, to 1, do this:

```
bit_array[25]=1
```

Comment: I updated `pip` beforehand see [link](https://packaging.python.org/installing/) Then execute `python -m pip install bitarray` on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid dependencies on third party packages, then it's pretty easy to roll your own clone of `bitarray`. Today I needed something that resembles `array.array`, and I only needed iteration and (little-endian) `tobytes`, so the following was sufficient:

```py
class BitArray:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self._arr = list(map(bool, iterable))
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._arr)
    def tobytes(self):
        return bytes(
            sum((bit << i for (i, bit) in enumerate(batch)), 0)
            for batch in itertools.batched(self._arr, 8))
```

If space consumption is a concern, then the following yields a more compact representation:

```py
class BitArray:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        last_i = 7
        self._blob = bytes(
            sum((bool(bit) << (last_i := i)
                 for (i, bit) in enumerate(batch)), 0)
            for batch in itertools.batched(iterable, 8))
        self._bits_in_last_byte = (last_i + 1) & 7
    def __iter__(self):
        return itertools.chain(
            (bool((x >> i) & 1) for x in self._blob[:-1] for i in range(8)),
            (bool((self._blob[-1] >> i) & 1)
             for i in range(self._bits_in_last_byte)))
    def tobytes(self):
        return self._blob
```