# Is there a mutable binary array in python?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, mutable

Is there a data structure in Python 3 that is an array of Boolean True or False? Additionally would this array be more memory efficient than an array of bytes?

I need to be able to change a value from True to False and access it by index; but I don't need to be able to change the size of the array.

edit: additionally, if a move command would be faster than indexing, this would be nice also

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an array of bits in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669178/how-to-create-an-array-of-bits-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

How about using array?

```
import array
a = array.array("B", [0]*10) #fix size of 10 - all False

a[1] = 1 # Mutable, Yay!
print(a)
```

It will use the least amount of memory and will give you a O(1) indexing

Comment: Would this array be more memory efficient than an array of bytes?

Comment: FYI, [`bytearray`, available since 2.6](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray) doesn't require an import or use of format codes & is much more efficient for certain purposes (in 2.x, `array` doesn't support the buffer protocol; it can't be used w/`memoryview` or other APIs that need "bytes-like objects"; `bytearray` supports the buffer protocol). Also, initializing the `array` with `[0] * x means making a temporary `list` 4-8x the size of the result, then iterating it; `array.array('B', b'\0' * 10)` (or `b'\1' * 10) is 2x faster, and gets even faster as the size increases.

Comment: @user4757074: `array.array('B')` _is_ a (dynamic) array of bytes (in the C sense), just like `bytearray`. Each additional value would cost (amortized, it grows by a multiplicative process to minimize reallocs) one additional byte to store, vs. a `list` or `tuple` which would cost one pointer sized variable for each value (so 4 or 8 bytes on 32 and 64 bit architectures respectively), so long as the `list`/`tuple` is filled with 0/`False and 1/`True` only (which are singletons in CPython, so you don't pay object overhead for each separate reference to them).

Answer (score 1):

Usually, it's best to pay the expense of using a byte per value rather than a bit, and you can use `bytearray` (a built-in since 2.6) for this purpose:

```
a = bytearray(100)            # 100 values all initialized to 0/False
# or initially true:
b = bytearray(b'\x01' * 100)  # 100 values all initialized to 1/True

# While you'll get 0 and 1 back, True and False can be assigned to it
a[1] = True
b[1] = False
```

This is usually be the best option, as it's more efficient to use byte addressing in most cases, unless it would cause data to spill from RAM to a swap file.

If you really need the space for a lot of flags, you'd need a third party package that optimizes to get one bit per value, e.g. [`bitarray`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray) (C extension for maximum speed, but still slower than `bytearray` for many purposes) or [`bitvector`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BitVector) or [`bitstring`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitstring) (Pure Python, to minimize compilation complications, and sometimes provide additional features more easily, but reliably slower than `bytearray` when not memory constrained).