# Python - Elegant way to deal with binary data that is not a multiple of 2

Tags: python, arrays, bit-manipulation, byte

I am working with binary data that is stored in a byte array and I need to access bits of arbitrary length inside this array. Performance is also a concern. Let me give a brief example:

```
# 11111111 | 11101111 | 01111100
byte_arr = bytearray([255, 239, 124])

# A corresponds to the first 6 bits, e.g. index 0-5
a = byte_arr[0]>>2 

# B corresponds to the next 2 bits, e.g. index 6-7
b = byte_arr[0] & 0x3

# C corresponds to the next 9 bits, e.g. index 8-16
c = int.from_bytes(byte_arr[1::], byteorder="big", signed=False)>>7
```

My above solution works, but a typical byte array has 20 bytes and therefore the code gets unreadable and is definitely not intuitive at a first glance.

Modules like struct won't help, because they ONLY can unpack bytes, e.g. 2^X

Comment: So, you'd like a function that returns an integer based on an arbitrary start index and length from your byte array?

Comment: Why don't just use a bytearray of size 17?

Comment: @NickMartin Yes, that's want I want

Comment: @DanielMesejo A byte array stores bytes but I need bits.

Comment: Can you use external libraries, if so check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669178/how-to-create-an-array-of-bits-in-python

Comment: I will have a look at the bit array module and take some performance measures, thanks for now!