# Fast reading and interpreting binary file

Tags: python, performance, binary

I have a huge binary file(several GB) that has the following dataformat:

4 subsequent bytes form one composite datapoint(32 bits) which consists of:

```
b0-b3    4 flag bits
b4-b17  14 bit signed integer
b18-b32 14 bit signed integer
```

I need to access both signed integers and the flag bits separately and append to a list or some smarter datastructure (not yet decided). At the moment I'm using the following code to read it in:

```
from collections import namedtuple
DataPackage = namedtuple('DataPackage', ['ie', 'if1', 'if2', 'if3', 'quad2', 'quad1'])
def _unpack_integer(bits):
    value = int(bits, 2)
    if bits[0] == '1':
        value -= (1 << len(bits))
    return value


def unpack(data):
    bits = ''.join(['{0:08b}'.format(b) for b in bytearray(data)])
    flags = [bool(bits[i]) for i in range(4)]
    quad2 = _unpack_integer(bits[4:18])
    quad1 = _unpack_integer(bits[18:])
    return DataPackage(flags[0], flags[1], flags[2], flags[3], quad2, quad1)

def read_file(filename, datapoints=None):
    data = []
    i = 0
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fh:
        value = fh.read(4)
        while value:
            dp = unpack(value)
            data.append(dp)
            value = fh.read(4)
            i += 1
            if i % 10000 == 0:
                print('Read: %d kB' % (float(i) * 4.0 / 1000.0))
            if datapoints:
                if i == datapoints:
                    break
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = read_heterodyne_file('test.dat')
```

This code works but it's too slow for my purposes (2s for 100k datapoints with 4byte each). I would need a factor of 10 in speed at least.

The profiler says that the code spends it's time mostly in string formatting(to get the bits) and in _unpack_integer().

Unfortunately I am not sure how to proceed here. I'm thinking about either using cython or directly writing some c code to do the read in. I also tried Pypy ant it gave me huge performance gain but unfortunately it needs to be compatible to a bigger project which doesn't work with Pypy.

Comment: drop the formatting and use masks directly on the read values. skip the "convert to string to get bits" phase.

Comment: thanks. well that seems to make a lot of sense. so to get i.e.quad2 i would need to do something along the lines data &= 00001111111111111100000000000000 but then i'm not sure how to cast this to an int16

Comment: For rigorousness' sake, 1 kB has **1024** B (not 1000).

Comment: I think I don't agree if I understand https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte correctly.

Comment: Right, I always forget about the "i".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the hint by Jean-François Fabre I found a suitable sulution using bitmasks which gives me a speedup of factor 6 in comparison to the code in the question. It has now a throuput of around 300k datapoints/s.

Also I neglected using the admittedly nice named tuples and replaced it by a list because I found out this is also a bottleneck.

The code now looks like

```
masks = [2**(31-i) for i in range(4)]
def unpack3(data):
    data = struct.unpack('>I', data)[0]
    quad2 = (data & 0xfffc000) >> 14
    quad1 = data & 0x3fff
    if (quad2 & (1 << (14 - 1))) != 0:
        quad2 = quad2 - (1 << 14)
    if (quad1 & (1 << (14 - 1))) != 0:
        quad1 = quad1 - (1 << 14)
    flag0 = data & masks[0]
    flag1 = data & masks[1]
    flag2 = data & masks[2]
    flag3 = data & masks[3]
    return flag0, flag1, flag2, flag3, quad2, quad1
```

The line profiler says:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    58                                           @profile
    59                                           def unpack3(data):
    60   1000000      3805727      3.8     12.3      data = struct.unpack('>I', data)[0]
    61   1000000      2670576      2.7      8.7      quad2 = (data & 0xfffc000) >> 14
    62   1000000      2257150      2.3      7.3      quad1 = data & 0x3fff
    63   1000000      2634679      2.6      8.5      if (quad2 & (1 << (14 - 1))) != 0:
    64    976874      2234091      2.3      7.2          quad2 = quad2 - (1 << 14)
    65   1000000      2660488      2.7      8.6      if (quad1 & (1 << (14 - 1))) != 0:
    66    510978      1218965      2.4      3.9          quad1 = quad1 - (1 << 14)
    67   1000000      3099397      3.1     10.0      flag0 = data & masks[0]
    68   1000000      2583991      2.6      8.4      flag1 = data & masks[1]
    69   1000000      2486619      2.5      8.1      flag2 = data & masks[2]
    70   1000000      2473058      2.5      8.0      flag3 = data & masks[3]
    71   1000000      2742228      2.7      8.9      return flag0, flag1, flag2, flag3, quad2, quad1
```

So there is not one clear bottleneck anymore. Probably now it's as fast as it gets in pure Python. Or does anyone have an idea for further speedup?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html), if you already have a c/c++ library that recognizes the data-strcture. The benefits are, the datastructues are still available to your python while the 'loading' would be fast. If you already have a c library to load the data you can use the function call from that library to do the heavy lifting and just map the data into your python structures. I'm sorry I won't be able to try out and provide proper code for your example (perhaps someone else cane) but here are a couple of tips to get you started

My take on how one might create bit vectors in python:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40364970/262108

The approach I mentioned above which I applied to a similar problem that you described. Here I use ctypes to create a ctypes data-structure (thus enabling me to use the object as any other python object), while also being able to pass it along to a C library:

https://gist.github.com/lonetwin/2bfdd41da41dae326afb

Comment: That is a good hint, thanks. I will try doing it in C soon to see wether I can gain even more performance than in my answer.