# Is Python bitwise shift really slow?

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, bit-shift

I must be overlooking something, but really don't see why the Python code is so slow...

Counting unique elements in an array where elements are in the range [−1,000,000..1,000,000] and use a bitvector to do this. The Java code, which uses `BitSet` is about 50 times faster than Python, which takes 9 seconds.

Is this maybe because when I initialise `bitvector = 0` Python doesn't reserve enough memory and the bitvector needs to be copied as it grows?

Python:

```
def solution(array):
    bitvector = 0
    count = 0
    for element in array:
        # transform -1,000,000 to 0 etc
        element_transformed = element + 1000000
        if bitvector >> element_transformed & 1 == 0:
            count += 1
            bitvector = bitvector | 1 << element_transformed

    return count
```

Test:

```
import unittest
import random

from .file1 import solution

class MySolutionTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_solution_random_all_unique(self):
        a = random.sample(range(-1000000, 1000001), 100000)
        self.assertEqual(100000, solution(a))
```

In Java:

```
package mypackage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.BitSet;
import java.util.List;


public class MyClass {

    public static int solution(List<Integer> array) {
        BitSet bitvector = new BitSet();
        int count = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            int elementTransformed = array.get(i) + 1000000;
            if(bitvector.get(elementTransformed) != true) {
                count++;
                bitvector.set(elementTransformed, true);
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    }
}
```

Test:

```
package mypackage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class MyClassTest {

    public MyClassTest() {
    }

    @Test
    public void testSolutionLong_RandomAllUnique() {
        ArrayList array = new ArrayList();
        for(int i = -1000000; i < 1000000; i++) {
            array.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(array);
        assertEquals(100000, MyClass.solution(array.subList(0, 100000)));

    }  
}
```

Comment: How big can your `bitvector` get? It's not just a dumb vector of bits, it's a fully-fledged arbitrary precision integer, so it's not as efficient as a simple vector. And CPython arithmetic isn't particularly fast, especially once the numbers are bigger than machine integers. If you really need speed, then there are various other options, eg using some kind of array of bytes.

Comment: Yes, it can get to two million bits. OK, maybe stupid of me to code it like this I guess as well :)

Comment: Why do you use `random.sample` in your Python test? Why not `shuffle`?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman thanks, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: No, from the look of your code, you're clearly not stupid. :) Using an int for this is easy, and it makes sense to try it first. A big bytearray is probably faster, and a Numpy array of uint8 even faster. And IIRC, there's a 3rd party bitarray library.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was very helpful.

Comment: No worries. BTW, it's probably a good idea to expand your tests to see what happens when the data _does_ have duplicate items.

Comment: It will use more memory, but the more pythonic and faster way is `len(set(a))`.

Answer (score 3):

Just trying to reply directly to the question you posed. It is not a simple question to answer why Python takes 9 seconds and Java is 50 times faster. Here you can get a good insight of a precedent discussion [Is Python slower than Java/C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672857/is-python-slower-than-java-c)

The way I like to look at it, is that Java is a Object Oriented language, while python is Object Based.

When looking at a bitwise operation, Java uses the primitive data types that are arguably faster due to not having boxing-unboxing operations and wrappers as a layer of abstraction. So looking at your code at every iteration python re-wrappes the integer as an object of type integer, while Java does not.

But again, I wouldn't take for granted that Java is always faster than Python. It is up to which library you are using and which problem you are trying to solve!

Answer (score 1):

The pythonic way to do this is

```
def solution(array):
    return len(set(array))
```

It is much faster, though will probably use more memory.

The `set` solution ran in about 100 ms for `10**6` samples from a `2*10**6` range.  I didn't even time the bit array because it took seconds.

When talking about lists on the order of `10**6`, it is worth the trade off.  Using `sys.getsizeof`, I measured the intermediate `set` as using 4.2 times the memory of the `list`.  The equivalent `int` bit array has about 1/30 the memory of the `list`.  This is on a 64 bit Linux system.